# PHP PDO: WHy doesn't work my code to insert multiple rows with different values?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, rows

I try to insert multiple rows with different values but I don't know why doesn't work

```
$id_poliza = $this->dbConnect->lastInsertId(); //With this, I save last insert id from last executed sql statement.

if($this->dataNewPoliza['d724'] == 'on')
    $disp1 = 1;
else
    $disp1 = 0;
if($this->dataNewPoliza['d58'] == 'on')
    $disp2 = 1;
else
    $disp2 = 0;
if(($this->dataNewPoliza['especial']) == '')
    $disp3 = 0;
else
    $disp3 = $this->dataNewPoliza['especial'];

if(($this->dataNewPoliza['ticket']) == '')
    $disp4 = 0;
else
    $disp4 = $this->dataNewPoliza['ticket'];

$sqlDispPol = "INSERT INTO disponibilidad_poliza (Id_Poliza, Id_Disponibilidad, Valor)
    VALUES (:idP,:idD1,:val1), 
           (:idP,:idD2,:val2), 
           (:idP,:idD3,:val3),
           (:idP,:idD4,:val4)";
$resultDisp = $this->dbConnect->prepare($sqlDispPol) or die ($sqlDispPol);

$resultDisp->bindParam(':idP',$id_poliza,PDO::PARAM_INT);

$resultDisp->bindParam(':idD1',1,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$resultDisp->bindParam(':val1',$disp1,PDO::PARAM_STR);

$resultDisp->bindParam(':idD2',2,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$resultDisp->bindParam(':val2',$disp2,PDO::PARAM_STR);

$resultDisp->bindParam(':idD3',3,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$resultDisp->bindParam(':val3',$disp3,PDO::PARAM_STR);

$resultDisp->bindParam(':idD4',4,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$resultDisp->bindParam(':val4',$disp4,PDO::PARAM_STR);

if($resultDisp->execute()) {
         //more code
    }
```

I want save from this form:

**Table disponibilidad_poliza**

```
Id_Poliza     Id_Disponibilidad   Valor
________________________________________
   1                1               1
   1                2               0
   1                3               especial10
   1                4               7

Note: $disp1 and $disp2 are checkboxes, $disp3 and $disp4 are inputs text
```

Maybe this way is incorrect and I appreceate If you put another way to do this please.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use bindValue() instead of bindParam().  It takes the same arguments but will work with raw integers and other scalars. The method bindParam() needs explicitly a parameter to be bound to and from what i see you doing you don't need to use it.